# Prove that if m|a and m|b then m|a+b

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help proving that if m|a and m|b, then m|a + b, and m|ac for any int c.

I was thinking that m|a and m|b => a = km and b = lm. Thus a + b = km + lm = (k + l)m. Since this is a multiple of m then m|(k + l)m and m|a + b. But I'm not sure if that proves it since I haven't proved m|a => m|ac and am not sure how to.

Sorry I don't know how to make everything look all math-y.

Comment: In case you want to learn how to make things all "math-y", [here's a tutorial and reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint $\ ac = (km)c.\,$ Can you show that is a multiple of $\,m\,?\ \ $

Comment: Your proof that if $m|a$ and $m|b$ then $m|a + b$ is good.  (Though perhaps you should mention $k,\ell \in \mathbb Z$.)  Are you sure you can't prove the other one?

Comment: yeah good call about k and l. and I think I got it, I think I was just overcomplicating it when I thought about it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know $$a|m$$ is *defined* to mean $$m=ka$$ for some integer $k$. So your proof is excellent.

Comment: yeah that's the definition of division I used, it just seems like I would have to proof

m|a => m|ac

in order to make that proof valid.

Comment: I think you're complicating it: you showed that $a+b=\text{something}\times m$ so that means $m|(a+b)$. All done!

Comment: PS - it is true that $a|x$ implies $a|(xy)$, and you can probably prove that too!

Comment: ahh ok, so do you think it works to use the def of division and say that thus $ \mathbf{ac = ckm}$, and since $\mathbf{ck} \in \Bbb{Z}$ then $\mathbf{m|ac}$ ?

Comment: Correct. And nice $\LaTeX$ skills!

Comment: $\mathcal{SWAG}$ 
thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You answer to the first part was correct. Here is to make to more 'mathy'. You gotta remember that 'mathy' means that each step is a logical consequence of the previous ones, in other words, you don't pull any assumptions out of thing air. Also, you write in 'mathy' talk of course; need to employ one of the methods of proofs. Here we will use direct proof: we proof *if $A$ then $B$* by supposing $A$ is true and arriving at the conclusion that $B$ is true.

Part 1. Suppose $m|a$ and $m|b$ (suppose $A$ is true). By definition of divisibility we have $mk=a$, and $ml=b$, where $k,$ and $l$ are some integers (note how we need to specify everything clearly). Adding the two together we have $a + b = mk + ml = m(k+l)$, where the last step is by the distributive property. Since both $k$ and $l$ are integers then so is $k+l$. Then, again by definition, we conclude $m|a+b$ (so we have arrived at $B$ and this completes our proof).

Part 2. Suppose $c$ is some integer, and $m|a$. So by definition $mk = a$ where $k$ is some integer. Now multiple by $c$ and we have $mkc = ac$. By associativity we have $m(kc) = ac$, and since both $k$ and $c$ are integers so is $kc$. Since $c$ is arbitrary, then by definition of divisibility we conclude $m|ac$ where $c$ is any integer.

Comment: thanks for your help! I actually just meant I didn't know how to use mathjax when I said it didn't look all mathy-sorry for the ambiguity. This is just my scratch work, so I was gonna write it out in complete sentences when I write it down